# Angular is creating many sockets with socket.io

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I write a nodejs, angular client/server application which uses socket connections.When I am in home page or  next page then it's create single socket and working correctly , when I go 2 level deeper (routing ) , it generates multiple sockets . I am using namespace , as in every page i need different socket connection based on different query objects .

This is the code for creating socket client in angular application

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Config } from '../config/env.config';
import { SocketConfig } from '../config/socket.config';   

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {

public host: string = Config.HOST;  

/**
 * * Creates a new SocketService
 */

initHomeSocket() {
    return io(this.host + SocketConfig.HOME);
}

initDashBoardSocket(dashboardId: string) {
    const query = 'dashboardId=' + dashboardId;
    return io(this.host + SocketConfig.DASHBOARD, 
this.setOptions(query));
}

 initDabaseSocket(dbId: string, queryId: string) {
    const query = 'queryId=' + queryId + SocketConfig.KEYJOIN + 
queryId;
    return io(this.host + SocketConfig.DATABASE, 
this.setOptions(query));        
}


 getSocketEmit(emitEvent: string, socket: SocketIOClient.Socket) {
    const observable = new Observable(observer => {
        socket.on(emitEvent, (data: any) => {
            observer.next(data);
        });
        return () => {
            socket.disconnect();
        };
    });
    return observable;
}

setOptions(queryString: string) {
    return { 'secure': SocketConfig.SECURE, 'reconnection': 
   SocketConfig.RECONNECT, 'reconnectionDelay': 
  SocketConfig.RECONNECT_DELAY, 'reconnectionDelayMax': 
  SocketConfig.RECONNECT_DELAYMAX, 'reconnectionAttempts': 
  SocketConfig.RECONNECT_ATTEMPTS, transport: SocketConfig.TRANSPORT, 
  query: queryString };
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and ask a specific question, please?

Comment: I have added code , this service i am calling in many pages (components) and in home page it's creating only one socket and in other page it's creating randomly many sockets.